# How to rid of unintentional vertical lines when transforming a UIImageView in iOS7.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiimageview, ios7.1

I am using transform to rotate images in my app, and it has been working fine up until iOS 7.1 (was fine in iOS 7). With iOS 7.1, when the image is rotated, I get odd unintentional lines showing up. The lines are not always static-- i.e., they change, even when my code is not specifically doing any animations. Here is an example. The fancy cloud to the left is the jpg I'm using. The vertical black line to the right is not something I've intentionally drawn. Note that this is a picture not a screen grab because screen grabs don't seem to capture the effect.

[image]

Here's an example of the transform I'm using on self (a UIImageView subclass):

```
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(self.rotation);
```

I'm also using a shadow for this UIImageView subclass:

```
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, -1);
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1;
    self.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
```

When I comment out these three lines of shadow code, the issue goes away. And I'm going to use this as a workaround right now. (I'll disable these lines for iOS7).

I've been unable to reproduce this effect in a simplified app, so presumably there's something else going on.

Anyone else ran into such stray vertical lines?

EDITS:

I've now tried

```
self.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeAffineTransform(CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(self.rotation));
```

replacing the previous transform and in addition to the previous transform, and still get the same result.

Comment: The transform is being applied to the image but not to the shadow...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried transforming the layer instead of the image view?

```
Self.layer.tranform = blah...
```

Comment: Interesting idea. It hasn't worked for me so far. Please see my edits above.

Comment: Hmm... Ok. Second idea. Try using a standard UIImageView instead of subclass. Just to try it.

Comment: That isn't really feasible in the context. I did, however, try the inverse. In my simplified example (in which I have yet to be able to reproduce this effect), I tried making the UIImageView a subclass. No help. Still can't reproduce the effect in a simplified example